# Nonlinear correction term to Debye-Huckel equation for asymmetrical electrolytes

Tags: physical-chemistry, ions

The Debye-Huckel equation for electrolytes in a solution is a differential equation for the potential function in the following form:

$$ \nabla^2\phi_j + \sum^{s}_{i=1}\frac{q z_i n^{(0)}_i}{\epsilon} \exp{\left(-\frac{q z_i \phi_j}{k_{\text{B}}T}\right)} = 0, $$

where $\phi_j$ is the potential of the $j$-th ion species, $s$ the number of species, $q$ the elementary charge, $z_i$ the number of charges, and $n_i^{(0)} = N_i/V$ the number density.

In the low potential limit $\left|q z_i \phi_j\right| \ll k_\text{B}T$, this becomes
$$ \left(\nabla^2 + \kappa^2\right)\phi_j = 0, \quad \kappa^2 = \sum^s_{i=1}\frac{q^2z_i^2n_i^{(0)}}{\epsilon k_\text{B}T}. $$

The relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye%E2%80%93H%C3%BCckel_theory#Mathematical_development) states without reference the following:

> This equation applies to electrolytes with equal numbers of ions of each charge. Nonsymmetrical electrolytes require another term with $\psi^2$.

I understand that in order to analytically solve the equation for an ion and obtain an expression for $\phi_j$, we have to assume spherical symmetry of the central ion and also the distribution of other ions, but I do not understand where and why the nonlinear term $\phi_j^2$ comes into the equation.